# What's the best way to push HTML into a new e-mail Body (OUTLOOK / VSTO)

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I have been able to setup a VSTO C# addin for Outlook which has a button on the "new mail" dialog (custom group on the "Message" Tab) and the button loads a form with a webview, which can pass back information to the add-in.

However I'm not sure how to pass in HTML into the new mail window now, to get started I just want the code to put "Hello World" into the body of the email - I've done a bit of googling on this and found nothing - any ideas?

at the moment I have the JS on the webpage running a callback on the Addin, and just doing a MessageBox.Show() but I need to figure out how to pass HTML email back based on what was selected on the webpage, but I'm sure if I can figure out just how to put HTML text into the body that will get me started.

any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either set the MailItem.HTMLBody property or use Inspector.WordEditor (returns Word's Document object) to manipulate the body content. Inspector is returned either from MailItem.GetInspector or Application.ActiveInspector.

Comment: I'm a bit of a n00b but having the property names should definitely help. Many Thanks.

Comment: No I think I'm still lost, here's what I mean - http://imageupper.com/i/?S0700010010013N1374849078614252

If I was creating a new Mailitem I would have no issues (I've tested this) - but I'm lost as to how to refer to the current open "new mail"

Comment: ahah Application.ActiveInspector is maybe what I'm looking for. will test. Thanks again

Comment: This worked for me : Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;  - thanks so much